# Portion of variance explained by individual properties with ANOVA

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, variance, excel

I have used the ANOVA test to compare the expected values of three datasets. The data sets contain data about the lifespans of three brands of frying oils. I have used Excel to perform the test and I have rejected the null hypothesis on $\alpha = 0.05 %$. Another task is to explain what portion of the total variance can be explained by the different properties of the individual oil brands. Do I understand the outcome of the Data Analysis plug-in that I should divide the values in the SS columns of rows `Between Groups` and `Total`? To be more specific, the result should be $\frac{48}{126} = 0.381$, i.e. we can explain 38 % of variance by the properties of the individual oil brands?

[image: ANOVA Results]